# How do I execute a math operation from a string with brackets?

Tags: javascript, math, eval

I am having a hard time executing math with brackets like `7( 7+(7 (7+1) ))(7)`. I am doing `eval()` on my operations. I thought to solve this is to convert this to `7*(7+(7*(7+1)))*(7)`. I tried

```
/(?!\*\()(\()/g
```

to avoid `'*('` on regexp and accept `'('` for replace method, but I fail. I am thinking of inserting `*` before `(`. How can I run `7( 7+(7 (7+1) ))(7)` properly? I am doing this for a calculator project.

Comment: Please updated your answer with your actual code (properly indented) and an example of the output or errors that they're getting.

Comment: You indeed need to insert `*` in the appropriate places. Rather than using `eval` (which would be a big issue if you're allowing people to type whatever they want), have you looked into implementing a more restricted parser? Like regex, but more in depth. With that, you could include the usage of parentheses to indicate multiplication as part of the parsing code. It seems [jison](http://zaa.ch/jison/) is a good one (it even has a calculator example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non regex solution. First replace all spaces with empty strings. Then replace the "(" with "*(" only if the parentheses is not preceded by an operator.

```js
var testString = ("7( 7+(7 (7+1) ))(7)").split("").filter((e) => e!=" ");
var arr = ["+", "-", "/", "("];

var resultString = testString.reduce(function(prev, curr, i)                               
 {
     if(arr.indexOf(i-1 ? testString[i-1] : "test") && curr == "(") { 
           return prev += "*(";
       }else{
           return prev += curr;
        }
        
  },"");

console.log(resultString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// (expr: string) => number
function evaluate(expr) {
  return eval(
    expr
      .replace(/\s+/g, '')             // remove spaces
      .replace(/([\d|\)])\(/g, '$1*(') // insert multiplication signs
    )
}
```